# Como fazer backup diários de Banco de Dados Mysql?

Tags: mysql, backup

Existe alguma ferramenta gratuita, ou até mesmo um *script* (`.bat`) que eu posso utilizar para fazer um *backup* automático do meu banco de dados?

Gostaria que esse *backup* fosse gerado salvando um único arquivo `.sql`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eu tenho um script que faz exatamente isso: um backup do MariaDB/MySQL e do PostgreSQL inteiro e faz rsync do arquivo para um outro local.

```cmd
#!/bin/bash

BASE_DIR=/tmp/backups
TMP_DIR="$BASE_DIR/$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)-$RANDOM"
DEST_DIR=/mnt/backups/database

if [ -d $TMP_DIR ] ; then
        rm -rf $TMP_DIR
fi;

mkdir -p $TMP_DIR
cd $TMP_DIR

pg_dumpall -U postgres | gzip > postgresql.sql.gz
mysqldump --all-databases -u root | gzip > mysql.sql.gz

if [ -d $DEST_DIR ] ; then
        rsync -a $BASE_DIR/ $DEST_DIR
fi;
```

E este script é invocado uma vez ao dia pelo cron:

```cmd
$ crontab -l
@daily /usr/local/bin/backup
```

Comment: Obrigado. Era exatamente isso que precisava.

Comment: Mas desta forma, se não tirar o banco do ar, não pode gerar problemas de integridade?

Comment: Bom, no meu caso, não é um grande problema. Mas se o banco tiver muitos acessos concorrentes, isso pode ser um problema. Se estiver usando InnoDB (ou algum storage transacional), basta adicionar a opção "--single-transaction"

Comment: Em tempo: vale notar que este script não é para ambientes profissionais, de alta concorrência e disponibilidade. Para tais ambientes, RTFM é muito mais recomendável do que uma entrada no stackoverflow, especialmente pq o profissional deve decidir as táticas com base no ambiente em que os sistemas estão rodando (ie: talvez seja melhor fazer o backup com base em dados de um slave)

Comment: Existe uma ferramenta opensource do Spoon que me ajudou pra caramba. Não somente com BKPs, mas outras tarefas. Busque Data integration do Pentaho.

Answer (score 3):

Existem mil formas. De uma olhada nesse projeto opensource que pode resolver seu problema:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/

Ou leia esse blog que sugere 10 maneiras diferentes.

http://www.noupe.com/how-tos/10-ways-to-automatically-manually-backup-mysql-database.html

Comment: Muito legal esse projeto. Vou tentar utiliza-lo.

Answer (score 3):

No linux você pode usar o crontab para executar essa tarefa diariamente.

Digite:

```cmd
crontab -e
```

Adicione a linha, substituindo os valores pelo do seu servidor:

```cmd
0 23 * * * mysqldump -h localhost -u usuario -psenha meuBanco > backup_meuBanco_$(date +%s).sql 2>&1
```

Salve (ESC :wq ENTER) e pronto, todo dia as 23 horas o seu script que vai fazer um dump salvará a sua base de dados.

Answer (score 3):

Não sou especialista em MySQL, mas aqui está a minha resposta, sendo um pouco mais simplista, e acredito que mais correta também.

Para realizar um backup com o banco online é necessário ter o binary log ativado.
Caso contrario você terá problema na integridade entre as tabelas no processo de restauração  *(transações que estavam em andamento durante o processo de dump)*

```
$ mysqldump --all-databases -F > /tmp/backup.mysql-full.sql
$ mysqladmin flush-logs
```

Então deve-se copiar os binarys logs gerados durante este processo.
Para restaurar este backup , deve-se aplicar o dump e os logs :

```
$ mysql < backup.mysql-full.sql
$ mysqlbinlog mysql.bin.XXX > dump.XX1.sql
$ mysql -f < dump.XX1.sql

$ mysqlbinlog mysql.bin.XX2 > dump.XX2.sql
$ mysql    < dump.XXX.sql
# e por ai vai... aplicando cada binary log.
```

## Importante

Não lembro o porque, mas se não me engano os grants de usuários não são salvos neste dump, então é preciso gera-los manualmente também!
Eu utilizo esta função shell que peguei em alguma outra questão aqui do stack (em ingles).

```
mygrants()
{
  mysql -B -N $@ -e "SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(
    'SHOW GRANTS FOR ''', user, '''@''', host, ''';'
    ) AS query FROM mysql.user" | \
  mysql $@ | \
  sed 's/\(GRANT .*\)/\1;/;s/^\(Grants for .*\)/## \1 ##/;/##/{x;p;x;}'
}
```

## Lembrete

O backup de dump não copia o seu arquivo de configuração `my.cnf`, então se atente de copia-lo manualmente!

## ***Alternativa***

Eu utilizo a ferramenta [xtrabackup da percona](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup) (freeware) para fazer backup do banco online.
Mas ai não é um backup em .sql, é praticamente uma copia dos datafiles+binary logs.
Fiz testes de backup e restore e funcionou perfeitamente.
Além de ter uma performance muito melhor que o dump porque é uma copia "crua".
Mas ai também tem a desvantagem de não tero dado em formato TXT.

Para referencia, faço o backup de um banco que roda a ferramenta de monitoramento Zabbix, com 7 GB de dados (tamanho da pasta do mysql onde ficam os dados). O backup é feito em no máximo 3 minutos. Considerando que é uma maquina virtual (VmWare ESXi) em um desktop, acho maravilhoso este tempo.

---

## ***Alternativa 2***

Em meus scripts , antes estava usando o xtrabackup , mas conforme meu banco foi crescendo comecei a ter alguns efeitos negativos de performance no ambiente durante o backup. Pesquisei métodos alternativos e passei a utilizar snapshots, copiando assim uma imagem completa do banco.

O processo de travar o banco, gerar o snapshot e liberar novamente não leva mais que 5 segundos.
Para isso utilizei o recurso de snapshot do LVM executo os seguintes passos (versão bem simplificada):

- No MySQL, forço um flush de dados para o disco e travo qualquer gravação nos datafiles :
  `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK`
- Gero snapshot no ponto de montagem que está os datafiles do MySQL :
  `lvcreate --snapshot myvg/lvmysql -n lv_snap1 -L 10G`
- Libero a gravação no MySQL novamente
  `UNLOCK TABLES`
- Monto FS do snapshot
  `mount /dev/myvg/lv_snap1 /mnt/bkp`
- Faço rsync dos arquivos para meu servidor de backup
- Desmonto o FS e removo o snapshot criado.
- No servidor destino eu ainda ativo o MySQL lá e executo um check antes de enviar para o backup final.

É preciso alguns cuidados no uso de snapshot, pois ele tem uma "vida" util que é o espaço alocado para ele. Esta vida util é o tempo que você tem para copiar o conteúdo dele para outro lugar e então destruir o snapshot.

Answer (score 3):

Existe uma classe (muito boa, recomendo) que faz isso

[MySqlBackup.Net](https://github.com/adriancs2/MySqlBackup.Net)

É bem simples de entender e de usar, e dá pra configurar inúmeras coisas, como quais tabelas que você quer receber o backup, se você deseja fazer também backup das configurações e etc.

Answer (score 2):

Em instâncias servidoras da Amazon [aws](/questions/tagged/aws) ([ec2](/questions/tagged/ec2)), adaptei minhas próprias soluções para não ter que pagar por outros softwares. Na solução para windows, implementei em C# usando a biblioteca [aws.net](/questions/tagged/aws.net). Para linux, instalei o #AWS-CLI e configurei as chaves de segurança ([iam](/questions/tagged/iam)). A partir daí criei o script abaixo para realizar o backup. Se quiser, pode ainda configurar a custódia dos backups no próprio [s3](/questions/tagged/s3) que ele expurga automaticamente.

```
#!/bin/bash
##########################################
# Backup database MySQL enviando para o S3
# Criado por Andre Mesquita
##########################################

#VARIAVEIS
DATAHORA=`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M`
FILESDIR='cd /sites/tmp'
TAR=/bin/tar
RM=/bin/rm

IPBANCO="127.0.0.1"
USERBANCO='seu usuario'
SENHABANCO='sua senha'
NOMEDOBANCO='nome do database'
NOMEDOBUCKET='meusbackups'

#Entrando no diretorio de backup
$FILESDIR

#Executa o backup do banco de dados
echo 'Realizando o backup do banco de dados...'
mysqldump --host=$IPBANCO --user=$USERBANCO --password=$SENHABANCO --databases $NOMEDOBANCO >  ./backup_$NOMEDOBANCO.sql

#Compactando o backup
echo 'Compactando arquivos do site...'
$TAR zcf $NOMEDOBANCO_database.bkp_$DATAHORA.tar.gz ./backup_$NOMEDOBANCO.sql

echo 'Enviando para o respositorio de backups...'
aws s3 cp ./$NOMEDOBANCO_database.bkp_$DATAHORA.tar.gz s3://$NOMEDOBUCKET/$NOMEDOBANCO_database.bkp_$DATAHORA.tar.gz

echo 'Excluindo o script descompactado...'
$RM $NOMEDOBANCO_database.bkp_$DATAHORA.tar.gz
$RM backup_$NOMEDOBANCO.sql

echo ' '
echo ' Operacao finalizada. '
echo ' '
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Para enviar arquivos para o S3, em ambiente windows, publiquei minhas ferramentas em https://github.com/avmesquita/AWS-Tools

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é isso que você precisa, mas segue um código completo pra fazer bkp do seu banco de dados, só salvar o código em um arquivo php, criar uma pasta chamada "db_bkp" e não esquecer de preencher os dados de acesso ao banco de dados. dentro do seu servidor de hospedagem vai ter uma opção chamada "tarefa cron" ou algo parecido, só ir lá e digitar o endereço pra esse arquivo e pronto

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); ini_set('display_startup_erros',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);//force php to show any error message

backup_tables(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);//don't forget to fill with your own database access informations

function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name)
{
    $link = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysqli_select_db($link, $name);
        $tables = array();
        $result = mysqli_query($link, 'SHOW TABLES');
        $i=0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
        {
            $tables[$i] = $row[0];
            $i++;
        }
    $return = "";
    foreach($tables as $table)
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM '.$table);
        $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($result);
        $return .= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$table.';';
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($link, 'SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
        $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
            {
                $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
                for($j=0; $j < $num_fields; $j++)
                {
                    $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                    if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                    if ($j < ($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
                }
                $return.= ");\n";
            }
        }
        $return.="\n\n\n";
    }
    //save file
    $handle = fopen('db_bkp/db-backup-'.time().'-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.sql','w+');//Don' forget to create a folder to be saved, "db_bkp" in this case
    fwrite($handle, $return);
    fclose($handle);
    echo "bkp efetuado com sucesso";//Sucessfuly message
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Esse eu criei pra usar sem o mysqldump:

```
$HOST         = "localhost";       # HOSTING
$USER_NAME    = "root";            # USUARIO DA BASE DE DADOS
$USER_PWRD    = "123456";          # PASSWORD DA BASE DE DADOS
$DB_PRIMARY   = "data base";       # NOME DA BASE DE DADOS PRIMARIA

// TABELA SELECIONADA PARA O BACKUP
$DB_SELECT = "$DB_PRIMARY";

// CONEXÃO BACKUP
$CONNECT_BACKUP = new mysqli("$HOST", "$USER_NAME", "$USER_PWRD", "$DB_SELECT");

// SETA O CHARSET DE COMUNICAÇÃO
$CONNECT_BACKUP->set_charset('utf8');

if ($CONNECT_BACKUP->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $CONNECT_BACKUP->connect_errno . ") " . $CONNECT_BACKUP->connect_error;
}

// INI FUÇÕES PARA A GERAÇÃO

// SQL QUERY ARRAY
function sqlQuery( $SQL_COMAND, $CONNECT ) {

    $RESULT_COMAND  = mysqli_query($CONNECT, $SQL_COMAND);

    while ($ROW_COMAND[]  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($RESULT_COMAND )) { } array_pop($ROW_COMAND);

    return $ROW_COMAND;

}

// SQL QUERY
function sqlQueryView( $SQL_COMAND, $CONNECT ) {

    $RESULT_COMAND  = mysqli_query($CONNECT, $SQL_COMAND);

    while ($ROW_COMAND[]  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($RESULT_COMAND )) { } array_pop($ROW_COMAND);

    foreach ($ROW_COMAND as $KEY => $VALUE) {

        foreach ($VALUE as $KEY2 => $VALUE2) {

            $COLS[] = $VALUE2;

        }

    }

    return $COLS;

}

// SQL INSERT
function sqlInsert( $DB_TABLE, $ROW_BACKUP ) {

    if ( $ROW_BACKUP != null ) {

    $SQL_INSERT = 'INSERT INTO `'.$DB_TABLE.'`'."\n";
    $SQL_INSERT .= '(';

    foreach ($ROW_BACKUP[0] as $KEY => $VALUE) {

    $COLS[] = "`$KEY`";
    }

    $COLS_IMP = implode( ', ', $COLS );
    $SQL_INSERT .= $COLS_IMP;

    $SQL_INSERT .= ")"."\n";
    $SQL_INSERT .= "VALUES"."\n";

    foreach ($ROW_BACKUP as $KEY => $VALUE) {

    $SQL_INSERT .= "(";

        foreach ($VALUE as $KEY2 => $VALUE2) {
            $ROWS[] = "'".$VALUE2."'";
        }

    $ROWS_IMP = implode( ', ', $ROWS );unset ($ROWS);
    $SQL_INSERT .= $ROWS_IMP;

    $SQL_INSERT .= "), "."\n";

    }

    $SQL_INSERT = trim($SQL_INSERT, '), '."\n");

    $SQL_INSERT .= "); "."\n"."\n";

    }

    return $SQL_INSERT;
}

// END FUÇÕES PARA A GERAÇÃO

// INI GERA O SCRIPT SQL
$SQL_TABLES = 'SHOW TABLES FROM `'.$DB_SELECT.'`;';

$ARRAY_ROWS_TABLES = sqlQuery( $SQL_TABLES, $CONNECT_BACKUP );

foreach ($ARRAY_ROWS_TABLES as $KEY => $VALUE) {

    foreach ($VALUE as $KEY2 => $VALUE2) {

        $SELECT_IN_TABLES[] = 'SELECT * FROM `'.$VALUE2.'`;'."\n";

        $SQL_SELECTS[] = $SELECT_IN_TABLES; unset($SELECT_IN_TABLES);

    }

}

foreach ($SQL_SELECTS as $KEY => $VALUE) {

    foreach ($VALUE as $KEY2 => $VALUE2) {

        $DB_NAME_X = explode ('`',$VALUE2);

        $DB_NAME_Q = $DB_NAME_X[1];

        //SQL CREATE TABLE
        $SQL_CREATE_TABLES = 'SHOW CREATE TABLE `'.$DB_NAME_Q.'`;';

        $ARRAY_ROWS_CREATE_TABLES = sqlQueryView( $SQL_CREATE_TABLES, $CONNECT_BACKUP );

        $SQL_CREATE .= $ARRAY_ROWS_CREATE_TABLES[1].";"."\n"."\n";  

        $SQL_QUERY = sqlQuery( $VALUE2, $CONNECT_BACKUP );

        $SQL_INSERTS .= sqlInsert( $DB_NAME_Q, $SQL_QUERY );

    }

}
// END GERA O SCRIPT SQL

// INI MOSTRA SCRIPT SQL PRONTO

//DEBUG
print_r ( $SQL_CREATE );

//DEBUG
print_r ( $SQL_INSERTS );

// END MOSTRA SCRIPT SQL PRONTO
```