# Bash - Backups Mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, backup, cron

Montei o `script` abaixo, para realizar backups de três bases MySQL. Gostaria de saber se está correto.

```
#VARIAVEIS
DATE=`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M`
HOSTNAME1="xxxxx"
HOSTNAME2="yyyyy"
HOSTNAME3="zzzzz"
USER='xyzedmar'
PASSWORD='xyz2'
DATABASE1='xxxxx'
DATABASE2='yyyyy'
DATABASE3='zzzzz'
DIR='http://site/mysql-bkp/'

#backup do banco de dados

mysqldump --host=$HOSTNAME1 --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD --databases $DATABASE1 > $DIR/backup_$DATABASE1_$DATE.sql
mysqldump --host=$HOSTNAME2 --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD --databases $DATABASE2 > $DIR/backup_$DATABASE2_$DATE.sql
mysqldump --host=$HOSTNAME3 --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD --databases $DATABASE3 > $DIR/backup_$DATABASE3_$DATE.sql
```

Mas preciso de ajuda para

1) como fazer apagar os arquivos de **x** dias anteriores, depois de feitos os backups atualizados?

2) Qual o código **Cron** para rodar o `script`?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: Não. Não consegui adaptar o código que sugeriram.

Comment: O que você não conseguiu fazer? Tentou executar a bash? Deu algum erro? Utilizo este código para fazer backup de meus bancos e funciona perfeitamente

Comment: As minhas rotinas de backup são todas automatizadas, sejam por scripts, softwares próprios, etc. Dá uma olhada no meu comentário nesta thread que pode ajudar você na sua implementação. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101888/21263 Abraço

Comment: > Você pode usar [esse script em Python](https://gist.github.com/jniltinho/5565364) que eu criei, ele faz backup de todas as bases de Dados. Baixe ele, execute um **chmod +x backup_mysql.py** e coloque na pasta **/usr/local/bin/**

Answer (score 0):

**Segue uma sugestão de implementação, você pode adaptar e utilizar em seu próprio script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
#E-mail do adm do servidor
EMAIL='seuemail@provedor.com'
#Data Atual
DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
#Diretório do backup
DIRETORIO=/var/backup
#Data Retroativa para apagar backup antigo, neste caso com data d-2
DATEP=`date +%Y%m%d --date="2 days ago"`
#Opções mysqldump para mais info acesse:
#http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_all-databases
#-x bloqueia todas as tabelas
#-e acelera inserções
#-A todos os bancos de dados
mysqldump -u usuarioBackup -pPassword -x -e -A > $DIRETORIO/bd.$DATE.sql

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then   #envia email se não efetuou backup
     echo "Backup MySQL falhou em $DATE" | mail -s "Erro no Backup MySQL" $EMAIL
else
    #remove o arquivo mais antigo se efetuou o novo backup
    rm $DIRETORIO/bd.$DATEP.sql
fi
```

Salve o arquivo com extensão `sh`, exemplo `backup.sh`. Para rodar este script automaticamente você deve programar o cron, para isso execute o comando `crontab -e` e programe conforme desejado. A linha abaixo fará com que o backup ocorra todos os dias as 00:00hs:

```
00 00 * * * sh /caminho/para/arquivo/backup.sh
```

[Para maiores informações sobre Cron](http://www.guiafoca.org/cgs/guia/intermediario/ch-manut.html)

**OBS: Caso não tenha familiaridade com vi para agendar o Cron execute `export VISUAL=nano; crontrab -e` e utilize o editor nano.**

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte linha na crontab para apagar os arquivos.

Para apagar os arquivos mais antigos do que 30 dias na pasta `/var/backup/mysql`:

```
find /var/backup/mysql/ -mtime +30 -type f -delete
```

Basta incluir esta linha na sua cron, como neste exemplo (Executar todos os dias às 18:40):

```
40 18 * * * find /var/backup/mysql/ -mtime +30 -type f -delete
```

Para editar a crontab, você pode executar `crontab -e` como usuário root.

Para rodar o seu script na Cron todos os dias às 15:30:

```
30 15 * * * sh /root/backup_mysql_script.sh
```

Para rodar o seu script na Cron nos sábados às 09:00:

```
0 09 * * SAT sh /root/backup_mysql_script.sh
```

Para mais informações sobre a Cron, [clique aqui](https://crontab.guru).

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Pacotes necessários: mysql, mysqldump e zip.

1. git clone https://github.com/SoundTooth/backupMysql.git
2. vi ./backupMysql/backup.sh
3. zip_passwd="SUA SENHA"
4. ESC + WQ + ENTER
5. sh ./backupMysql/backup.sh

Download e instruções: 
https://github.com/SoundTooth/